# Spring JSTL date format to DD-MM-YYYY

Tags: java, spring, jstl

I am using JSTL tags to display views

```
    <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
 <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

my expression

```
<td><c:out value="${project.projectStartdate}"/></td>
```

but it Displaying in **YYYY-MM-DD** but i want in the format **DD-MM-YYYY**

Comment: Can you try this: `<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"%>
<fmt:formatDate pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" value="${project.projectStartdate}" />`

Comment: @BalusC Please give URL if it is duplicate

Comment: Check top of question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"%> 
<fmt:formatDate pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" value="${project.projectStartdate}" />
```

Comment: what is the difference between 
   <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>

<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"%>